# how to detect visible (in view) element using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

I have a div (#diagram) larger than the actual visible area in my browser. #diagram contains up to 1500 "boxes" (other div elements) and I would like to know which of these 1500 boxes are actually really visible to the user so that I can populate them using ajax when they come into view. I actually do have some working code but that goes through all elements triggered by the onscroll() event. This works so so in Chrome but of course my client HAS to use the evil browser IE8 where the looping of all elements upon scrolling completely forces my application on its knees.

Is there some sort of event that is fired when an element comes into view or any other option to detect "true" visibility?

Environment: jQuery/jQueryUI (latest), Internet Explorer 8

Thanks in advance :-)

./cj

Comment: As far as I know there is no better way than to detect the scrolling position. Can you show your current code?

Comment: @Thomas Showing the code is difficult - client considerations and all. Would have to do a lot of cleaning. Basically I receive a load of customers through ajax and in js render them and append them to a div using jquery. All lowest level divs are positioned absolute to have them line up to a background grid

Answer (score 2):

What if you go through all your boxes just once when they have been rendered and group them into "pages" - collections of references to DOM divs that are visible between [y1, y2] vertical coordinates of your parent div. You'll have `<total height of parent div> / <visible height of parent div>` pages.
You preload content of the 1st page, and then on each scroll event you'd check if content for the next page of boxes should be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Refer -

[**Element ‘in view’ Event Plugin**](http://remysharp.com/2009/01/26/element-in-view-event-plugin/)

When the window is scrolled, the event checks the position of the elements against the viewport height and the scrollTop position.

And

[**Lazy Load Plugin**](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)

Lazy Load is a jQuery plugin written in JavaScript. It delays loading of images in long web pages. Images outside of viewport (visible part of web page) wont be loaded before user scrolls to them

Comment: I simply cannot get the inview event to fire... I have     $('.customer').bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
        alert(visible);
    }); but nothing happens :-( Can position: relative disturb anything?